# I can't scroll my div content perfectly into bottom

Tags: javascript, css, html

I was going to make my auto scroll div content that was going to scrolled into bottom, but somehow it scrolled at least 1 lines before the last line. this div was supposed to be like textarea, but i do't want to use textarea because it will not format any html.

i was tried to make my scroll condition to be *minus one* and scroll event be *plus one*

I had javascript like this

```js
var chatLog = document.getElementById('chatlog');
var logLength = chatLog.scrollHeight - chatLog.offsetHeight;

chatLog.innerHTML += msg;

if (chatLog.scrollTop < logLength - 1) {
    chatLog.scrollTop = logLength + 1;
}
```

and css like this

```css
.chatlog {
    width: 70%;
    height: 200px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 10px;
    flex: 1;
    overflow: auto;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 0;
}
```

i expect the output will be last line, but actual outpus is one line before last line.

Comment: Please create an [mcve].  And honestly, it's unclear what the problem is - "minus one" and "plus one" _what_?

Comment: Please add your HTML in addition to your (full) javascript and css.

Comment: i had container like this

```html
<div id="home">
 <div onclick="pageScroll()" id="chatlog" class="chatlog"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @cale_b what i mean was "decreasing conditional value" and "increasing scroll variable"